# Check application install

Tags: applications, installation

I want to write a simple program (java) run on desktop to first check some application is already installed in the device and if not install it. For installation part I may be use to adb install command. How to check whether application is already install in the device.

Comment: To VTClers: Though being asked from a developers standpoint (and development questions *are* off-topic here), this question is of interest to power-users as well. Scenario: Check whether a certain app is installed on a device attached via ADB, without having to use graphical stuff.

Comment: Why do you need to check for app's existence before installing?  The `-r` switch to `adb install` command performs this check already and re-installs the app (keeping all the data) if it already exists.

Comment: Initially I do not need to re install same app if already installed. I will give a info message if install..

Answer (score 1):

You can find your answer e.g. [at Github](https://gist.github.com/davidnunez/1404789), and details in the [developers documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#pm):

```
adb shell 'pm list packages [options] <FILTER>'
```

> Prints all packages, optionally only those whose package name contains the text in .
>
> Options:
>
> ```
> -f: See their associated file.
> -d: Filter to only show disabled packages.
> -e: Filter to only show enabled packages.
> -s: Filter to only show system packages.
> -3: Filter to only show third party packages.
> -i: See the installer for the packages.
> -u: Also include uninstalled packages.
> --user <USER_ID>: The user space to query.
> ```

As you can see: Unless you specified the `-u` parameter, `pm list` will only show installed apps. Filter the output for the package you want to deal with. If the output is "empty", the package is not installed:

```
adb shell 'pm list packages' | grep -x 'com.foobar'
```

should output nothing if `com.foobar` is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you make a reference to both java and adb in your question it sounds as if you're familiar with both.

Just have your Java application as a wrapper to perform adb system commands.

Using the system commands to adb, you could use the same Java program (adb wrapper) to check for the installs and actually perform the installs.

You can replace the "pm list packages" with any of the adb commands do perform your intentions.

This is the java class you can use.  Of course your java application can search the return (response) string for the apps you want to verify.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class checkandroid {

    static int exitstatus;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String shellcommand = "/opt/android/android-studio/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell pm list packages";

        String response = runit(shellcommand);

        System.out.println(response);

    }
    static String runit(String inputstr) {
        String output = "";
        exitstatus = 0;

        Process p = null;

        // -----------------------------------------------

        try {

            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(inputstr);

            InputStream cmdStdOut = null;
            InputStream cmdStdErr = null;

            cmdStdOut = p.getInputStream();
            cmdStdErr = p.getErrorStream();

            String line = "";
            String line1 = "";
            BufferedReader stdOut = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    cmdStdOut));
            BufferedReader stdErr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    cmdStdErr));
            while ((line = stdOut.readLine()) != null) {
                // logger.info(line);
                // System.out.println(line);
                output += line + "\n";
            }
            stdOut.close();
            System.out.print("Error Status: ");
            while ((line1 = stdErr.readLine()) != null) {
                // logger.info(line);
                System.out.println(line1);
                output += line1;
            }
            stdErr.close();

            try {
                p.waitFor();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            exitstatus = p.exitValue();
            System.out.println(p.exitValue());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // -----------------------------------------------

        return output;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Izzy and L.D James I combined both and make success :)

Comment: @user3734225 You're very welcome! Consider contributing back to the community by marking it solved by clicking the check mark.  This will flag a good resource for the next person having a similar question.  Glad to be of service!